# how to make a pick list as searchable pick list?

Tags: visualforce

Reference : http://in.bookmyshow.com/hyderabad
When a user clicks in Movie field, he is able to select a movie(shown as Pick list) or if user types then accordingly movies pop up.
How to do this type of searchable pick list in salesforce?
Is this possible with SKUID, if so how can we do it?

Thanks...

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this http://anupjadhav.com/2013/02/01/jquery-autocomplete/ but with the support for normal picklist behavior.